# Half of the New Privilege message is in a language I don't speak

Tags: bug, status-review, languages, achievements-dialog, localization

I just earned the "access moderator tools" privilege, but the message under the achievements dialog is a bit odd:

[image]

I don't speak Spanish and (as far as I know) never indicated to Stack Overflow that I speak Spanish. Yet, the second sentence of the message is in Spanish and it isn't just a repeat of the first sentence, it has a whole new meaning. Even more interesting is that the message I see when I switch to Stack Overflow Meta is normal:

[image]

Can this bug be fixed?

Comment: Seems like a common bug with notifications that they some times show up in another language. MSE: [Wrong language in recent achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376522)

Comment: This exact issue with this exact achievement was also reported on [Meta PLDI](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/284/109)

Comment: Yes it's a cross network bug. It's still happening, on all sites.

Comment: I am (again) [status-review]ing this separately from the MSE bug report. While it's possible (or perhaps even highly likely that) this is the same bug, we have no way of knowing if resolving the russian language bug will also address this spanish language bug as we do not have access to the code responsible. We've also seen instances of bugs that SE needed to fix individually (like the series of HTML entities bug reports).

Comment: It still blows my mind that apparently they have each sentence separately tokenised.  That means the door is open for not only half the message appearing in a different language because of mysterious design choices, but to also get sentences which are not even tangibly related to each other because someone used the wrong lookup key to stitch them together.